# Multiple project releases to be build as seperate with Sonar and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

How can I build different project releases which different project in sonar?

We have code base as trunk, release 1, release 2. On doing `mvn sonar:sonar` it picks the name from pom and add as one project in sonar dashboard.

Comment: change the sonar.projectName property in your POM file to Project-RELEASE#

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the "sonar.branch" property: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters